# Windows Phone 8 Dev On Windows 7, Device Only

Tags: windows-phone-7

I got a Windows 7 32-bit machine, can I do MS Windows Phone 8 dev on the machine but let it deploy directly to the device and not use the Windows Phone 8 Emulator that does require Windows 8 with a 64-bit machine?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to download the Windows Phone 8 SDK [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471), you've the System Requirements.

That indicates :

```
Supported Operating System

 Windows 8, Windows 8 Pro 

Operating system type:
 Windows 8 64-bit (x64) client versions

Hardware: 
 6.5 GB of free hard disk space
 4 GB RAM
 64-bit (x64) CPU
```

If you want to develop a project for Windows Phone 8, you need a Windows 8 OS in 64 bits.

Also, the SDK windows phone 8 install the Windows Phone 8 deployer... for deploy on the Windows phone 8 device...

Windows Phone 7 use Zune, not Windows Phone 8.

You can try to install the SDK in a Windows 7, but when you execute this, a message indicate your OS is not compatible appear... even if I had a Lumia 920, I bought my Windows 8 just for that... ( the deployement)